# In redux, my reducer is returning no results in the console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am utilizing redux together with reactjs and applying the middleware "thunk" in  between. In the action creator I am running an http request and I send the response as an object to the reducer and then the reducer returns that data.

I am trying to display that data in the console (or more importantly in the component to show in the front-page) but I seem to be doing it wrong. Here is the codes:

action creator
actions.js

```
export const SHOW_GALLERY = 'SHOW_GALLERY';
import axios from 'axios';

// FETCH THE IMAGES
export const actionGallery = () => {
  return ( dispatch ) => {
    axios.get('../images')
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        dispatch(showGalleryAsync(res.data));
      }
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
}
function showGalleryAsync(images) {
  return {
    type: SHOW_GALLERY,
    payload: images
  }
}
```

reducer
images.js

```
import { HEAD_SELECTED, SHOW_GALLERY } from '../actions/actions';

export function showGallery(state=[], action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SHOW_GALLERY:
      let images = action.data;
      let arr = [];
      action.payload.map((i, index) => {
        arr.push(i);
      });

      return arr;
    default:
      return state;
    }
  }
```

component
Gallery.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { actionGallery } from '../actions/actions';

class Gallery extends React.Component {
  render() {

    console.log(this.props);

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>This is the Gallery.</h1>
        <br />
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-8">
                <h2>H2 h2 h2 2h2 </h2>
                  { this.props.actionGallery.map((link, index) => {
                    return <img src={link}></img>
                  }) }
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    showGallery: state.showGallery
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    actionGallery: actionGallery
  }, dispatch)
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Gallery);
```

Comment: I don't see where you are dispatching `actionGallery` to perform the http request?

Comment: I tried to put it in the action creator in the inner return function

Comment: I don't think you've called your action.  It looks like axios returns a promise: this.props.actionGallery needs to resolve the promise but you're calling .map on it.

Comment: @Chris What I mean is where are you calling `actionGallery` (or more specifically `this.props.dispatch(actionGallery())` in your component? is it in the gallery component or a HOC?

Comment: I tried this.props.dispatch(actionGallery()) in my component but it keeps returning undefined (and spamming it in console)

Comment: I tried this.props.dispatch(actionGallery()) in my component but it keeps returning undefined (and spamming it in console). also I just tried this.props.actionGallery().then(res => console.log(res))     and it says cannot read property .then of undefined and the url is correct too

Comment: Inner function within `actionGallery` is not returning anything to the outer function to return the promise, hence you cannot use the promise chain. I haven't used axious before but I assume that's an asynchronous function? if so put a `return` infront of axios e.g. `return axios.get('..') ....`